# VBA Radius of a circle

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub area(p As Single, radius As Integer)
Dim answer As Single



' area of circle is 3.14 x r(sq)


Const p = 3.14

answer = p * radius^

radius = InputBox("Enter the radius")




area = answer

MsgBox asnwer

End Sub
```

Hey all so im trying to do a simple VBA programme to calculate radius of circle. Where just a box appears . you enter the radius and answer is given back in a msgbox. when

Comment: Change `Sub area(p As Single, radius As Integer)' to `Sub area()` .Change `answer = p * radius^` to `answer = p * val(radius)^2` and move it after inputbox line. Delete line `area = answer` it is not used.

Comment: hey Ahmed thanks for your reply, why is area = answer not used in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s best practice to add

```
Option Explicit
```

at the beginning of each module. This will ensure you’re declaring all variables and prevent most of typos.

After that, correct this line:

```
MsgBox asnwer
```

You have a typo. Should be

```
MsgBox answer
```

Also, you don’t need to declare this variables as parameters.

```
Sub area(p As Single, radius As Integer)
```

Replace that line for:

```
Sub area()
```

Also check some other adjustments I made.

Final code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Area()

    Dim answer As Double
    Dim radius As Double

    ' area of circle is 3.14 x r(sq)

    ' Define PI constant
    Dim p As Double

    p = WorksheetFunction.Pi()

    ' Ask for the radius
    radius = InputBox("Enter the radius")

    ' Calculate area
    answer = p * radius ^ 2

    ' Show the user the answer
    MsgBox answer

End Sub
```

Comment: Good tutorial content ! *(+1)*

Comment: Why As Double? why radius as double :P ?

Comment: Double is prefered for math calculations as it provides a better precision. Check this link for more info. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/comparing-double-vs-single-data-types-in-vb6/

Comment: Please also consider to mark the answer if it helped you

Comment: Done! Thanks for that

Comment: Im still getting an error... Type declaration character does not match declared data type

Comment: In what line are getting it? you can use F8 to step through each line

Comment: I have updated the code to use the pi worksheet function. please try again with new code.

Comment: It didnt like the radius^ part for some reason.. so I just put radius * radius

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub test3()
Dim radius as double
Dim area as double
Radius = 4
Area = 3.14*radius^2
 
'Here the ^symbol is used to raise radius to the power 2

Debug.print " value of radius is: "& radius
Debug.print " value of radius is: "& area
End sub
```